# print OrderedDictionary array values?

Tags: c#, ordereddictionary

Line: gets one line from the file, it's iterate

```
string[] values = line.split(","); // ex: ["hi, "test", "no", "sup"]

OrderedDictionary od = new OrderedDictionary();
Tuple<int, string[]> innerTuple = new Tuple<int, string[]>(int.Parse(value[0], values);
```

I cannot seem to find a way to print out the value array. However, I can print out the arrays by using regular dictionary (I don't like how dictionary can mix up the order of insertion).

Comment: And how are you printing out the arrays when you use a `Dictionary`?  What happens when you try to do that with an `OrderedDictionary`?

Comment: Use another data structure...

Comment: @Servy With dictionary, I used foreach to get the key, then do forloop for every value[index] with that key, ex: `Console.WriteLine(dict[k][index])`. I tried to do it in OrderedDictionary, not a clue.

Comment: @user7190976 And what problem did you have implementing that with an `OrderedDictionary`?

Comment: @Servy I tried to use `foreach(var k in od.keys) { for(int index = 0; index < od[k]. ; index++)` then when placing a dot after the `od[k]` it only displays "Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, or ToString" which I'm looking for Length or Count.

Comment: Raven is right, I didn't realize before that you were using an old obsolete collection.  You should be using `SortedDictionary` for an ordered key/value pair collection.

Comment: @Servy Doesn't that sort alphabetic order or number? or does it insert the data in the correct order as it's inserted?

Comment: @user7190976 It orders it however you indicate that they should be ordered, as per the comparer.  If you don't want to order based on the key at all, then I'd question why you want to have a lookup based collection in the first place.

Comment: @Servy I wanted to ensure that existing key is getting latest information. based on the location of the textfile. Basically, putting updated value to key then move the key to the end of dictionary index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry item in od)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

UPDATE:

If you have a string array as the value then you should try something like this:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry item in od)
{
    if (item.Value is string[])
    {
        foreach (string str in (string[])item.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A string item: " + str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work. Item.value will return string[].

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, I see. Sorry then.